# Weird reaction of Adapter when ListView items go out of Border

Tags: android, adapter

please take a look at this Adapter, i have a weird problem with that, it reads data from database, when the row's are in border of the listview, they are find and no problem, but when they go out of listview border ( so i have to scroll down) every thing gets mixed up and nothing then is on its place, have you guys seens this beofore?

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mCursor.getString(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mCursor.getPosition();
}
// mCursor.getPosition()

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
   if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_discuss, 
 null);
          this.convertview=convertView;


    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

    holder.theMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    holder.theName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGname);
    holder.theImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGimage);

    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp =  
  (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) holder.theName.getLayoutParams();



     String Namer= mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("username"));
           String namer[] = Namer.split("\\@");
           String imagenamer=namer[0];

    holder.theName.setText(imagenamer);

 holder.theMessage.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("message")));

    int isright=  
 Integer.valueOf(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("isright")));

    if(isright==0){

        holder.theMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

        holder.wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

        lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.theName.setLayoutParams(lp);

        android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
 android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT     ,Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.theImage.setLayoutParams(params);

        holder.theImage.setPadding(10,0,0,0);
        holder.wrapper.setPadding( ImageWidth+10,40,0, 0);
        holder.theName.setPadding( ImageWidth+25, 0,0, 0);
        //(left, top, right, bottom)
        File file= new File("storage/sdcard/LifeMatePrivate/ProfileImage
/ProfileImage,imagechange_2,"+imagenamer+",.jpg");
        if(file.exists()){
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File("storage/sdcard
/LifeMatePrivate/ProfileImage
/ProfileImage,imagechange_2,"+imagenamer+",.jpg")).resize(ImageWidth,   
ImageHeight).centerCrop().into(holder.theImage);
        }else{
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File("storage/sdcard
/LifeMatePrivate/ProfileImage/Default.jpg")).resize(ImageWidth,  
ImageHeight).centerCrop().into(holder.theImage);
        }



    }else{

    holder.theMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);

    holder.wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    holder.theName.setLayoutParams(lp);

    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
 ,Gravity.RIGHT);
    holder.theImage.setLayoutParams(params);

    holder.theImage.setPadding(0,0,10,0);
    holder.wrapper.setPadding(0,40, ImageWidth+10, 0);
    holder.theName.setPadding(0, 0, ImageWidth+25, 0);
    //(left, top, right, bottom)
    File file= new File("storage/sdcard/LifeMatePrivate/ProfileImage  
/ProfileImage,imagechange_2,"+imagenamer+",.jpg");
    if(file.exists()){
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File("storage/sdcard/LifeMatePrivate
 /ProfileImage/ProfileImage,imagechange_2,"+imagenamer+",.jpg")).resize(ImageWidth, 
 ImageHeight).centerCrop().into(holder.theImage);
    }else{
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File("storage/sdcard/LifeMatePrivate
 /ProfileImage/Default.jpg")).resize(ImageWidth, 
 ImageHeight).centerCrop().into(holder.theImage);
    }

    }


    if(!mCursor.isLast()){
        mCursor.moveToNext();   
    }

    convertView.setTag((ViewHolder)holder);

   }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: i think the problem must be with my condition     if(!mCursor.isLast()){
        mCursor.moveToNext();   
    }

Comment: I think you are probably right about the condition.  I had a similar problem because of conditions I created that weren't working properly inside of getView

Comment: well i assume when it reaches end of list, cursor says im at last, so doesnt move to next, this could be the problem, im already looking for real answer and update it upon finding

Comment: Why you don't extend CursorAdapter? It'll look better here.

Comment: what do you mean look better dude?

Comment: the problem appears to be when convertView is not null, because it happenes when its not null i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Well,the purpose of ViewHolder is to not call FindViewbyId()'s every time, and whenever you view scrolls out of borders, android recycles the view,so you have to rebuild it. fixed the problem by changing the first part of getView like this :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
   if (convertView == null) {
    System.out.println("convertview null");
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_discuss, null);
          this.convertview=convertView;




    holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

    holder.theMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    holder.theName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGname);
    holder.theImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGimage);


    convertView.setTag((ViewHolder)holder);

   }else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    System.out.println("convertview not null");
   }
  ////rest of the code
```